# Maintaining State with a Custom Widget Controller for PlutoGrid?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, pluto-grid

So I am relatively new to flutter.  I really don't care for the solutions I see out there for maintaining state.  In my opinion, there is an ungodly amount of plumbing required to do this that quite frankly should be obfuscated from the developer, but I digress.

What about using a custom Widget controller for PlutoGrid.   I do see a Scroll Controller class being mentioned a lot with reference to grids, including PlutoGrid.

In essence, what I'm looking for is a good example of a simple solution that populates a PlutoGrid using an JSON API via a list of custom class objects.  The icing on the cake would be a custom Widget controller for PlutoGrid.

Comment: Can PlutoStateManager be used for this?  The name of this class strongly suggests that it can.

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76617271/how-do-i-dynamically-load-a-plutogrid-from-an-api-call-that-returns-json/